# A question on shifting and scaling graphs (in calculus, algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reviewing high school algebra before studying the university calculus.
I have a question about shifting and scaling graphs.
My problem is as follows.
$$y=\sqrt{1-{x\over2}}$$
I need to sketch the graph of this function when I already know the graph of $y=\sqrt x$.

First, I rewrote the expression.$$y=\sqrt{{-1\over2}(x-2)}$$
**Incorrect Answer**
I thought I needed to shift the graph by 2 units, and then stretch the graph in the $x$ direction by 2. Then I tried to reflect the graph across the $y$-axis.
**Correct Answer**
Actually, I know the correct answer. I need to reflect the graph across the $y$-axis first. Then I need to stretch the graph in the $x$ direction by 2. Finally, I need to shift the graph by 2 units to the right.
The problem is, I don't understand why I should do it this way. Why is the first approach a wrong answer? Please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: Break it down step by step. Correct: $\,\sqrt{x} \;\mapsto\; \sqrt{-x} \;\mapsto\; \sqrt{-x/2} \;\mapsto\; \sqrt{-(x-2)/2}\,$. Incorrect: $\dots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$y=\sqrt{1-{x\over2}}$$

1. > **Correct Answer** I don't understand why I should do it this way.
   >
   > I need to reflect the graph $y=\sqrt x$ across the $y$-axis first.

   Start with the graph of $$y=f(x).$$ Applying the above reflection
   gives $$y=f(-x).$$

   > Then I need to stretch the graph in the $x$ direction by 2.

   This then gives $$y=f\left(-\left(\frac12x\right)\right).$$

   > Finally, I need to shift the graph by 2 units to the right.

   This finally gives
   $$y=f\left(-\left(\frac12(x-2)\right)\right)\\=f\left(1-\frac
   x2\right),$$ as required.
2. > **Incorrect Answer** Why is this approach wrong?
   >
   > I thought I needed to shift the $y=\sqrt x$ graph by 2 units, and then stretch the graph in the $x$ direction by 2. Then I tried to
   > reflect the graph across the $y$-axis.

   Starting again with the graph of $$y=f(x),$$ the above sequence of
   transformations gives $$y=f(x-2),$$ then
   $$y=f\left(\left(\frac12x\right)-2\right),$$ then
   $$y=f\left(\left(\frac12(-x)\right)-2\right)\\=f\left(-2-\frac
   x2\right).$$

Here's a related discussion: [How does one explain that transformations 'inside' a function operate in the opposite direction than intuition suggests?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5614/372).